# Loading from a plist error Swift

Tags: arrays, string, swift, plist

I'm reading from a plist to load into an Array. At first, I only had one item for the array in the plist. That loaded fine.

However, I deleted that entry and put 2 new entries into the plist (both of which are different from the original entry).

Now, when I run and swift "reads" from the plist, it only shows the single old entry.

It sounds like something swift is doing wrong on its end. I tried to delete derived data, thinking that maybe something outdated was being stored in there, but it didn't work.

Has anyone experienced something like this? Please help if you get a chance. I've been stuck on this one for quite some time now!

Comment: Please show some code, i am running in a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your plist included in your bundle? If so, plists included in the bundle are immutable (readonly) and nothing you do will change it.

** Note: In the past, and possibly still now, these plists can be modified.  This behavior is different from actual devices.

You'll have to create a new plist dynamically if you want to edit it and persist those changes.

If you are already creating your plist dynamically then the error is different and I will remove this answer.  Please notify.

Comment: It should be if that's the standard thing that happens when I create it, but how would I go about checking/doing that?

Comment: Are you creating it programmatically, or is it a plist in xcode.

Comment: Then it is included in your bundle, which means it is immutable.  You'll never be able to change its contents.

Comment: Well that answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I ran into the same thing before!

Comment: If you create it programmatically, you can change it, yes.  If it's included in your bundle, No.  I built a library to help w/ interacting with them programmatically if you want to check it out: https://github.com/LoganWright/PlistModel